# PHP Like thing similar to MySQL Like, for if statement?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I want an if statement that uses same thingy like mysql `something LIKE  '%something%'`

I want to build an if statement in php.

```
if ($something is like %$somethingother%)
```

Is it possible?

The reason for me asking this question is that I don't want to change the MySQL command, it's a long page with many stuff on it, I don't want to build a different function for this.

Let me know if this is possible, if possible then how to do it .

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> if ($something is like %$somethingother%)
>
> Is it possible?

no.

> I don't want to change the MySQL command, it's a long page with many stuff on it

Use some good editor, that supports regular expressions in find & replace, and turn it to something like:

```
if(stripos($something, $somethingother) !== FALSE){

}
```

Answer (score 31):

I know, this question isn't actual but I've solved similar problem :)

My solution:

```
/**
 * SQL Like operator in PHP.
 * Returns TRUE if match else FALSE.
 * @param string $pattern
 * @param string $subject
 * @return bool
 */
function like_match($pattern, $subject)
{
    $pattern = str_replace('%', '.*', preg_quote($pattern, '/'));
    return (bool) preg_match("/^{$pattern}$/i", $subject);
}
```

Examples:

```
like_match('%uc%','Lucy'); //TRUE
like_match('%cy', 'Lucy'); //TRUE
like_match('lu%', 'Lucy'); //TRUE
like_match('%lu', 'Lucy'); //FALSE
like_match('cy%', 'Lucy'); //FALSE
```

Comment: I like it - a small change. The pattern line should be `$pattern = str_replace('%', '.*', preg_quote($pattern,'/'));`. Otherwise forward slashes won't be escaped for preg_match().

Answer (score 5):

look on [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function

Answer (score 5):

Use this function which works same like SQL **LIKE** operator but it will return boolean value and you can make your own condition with one more if statement

```
function like($str, $searchTerm) {
    $searchTerm = strtolower($searchTerm);
    $str = strtolower($str);
    $pos = strpos($str, $searchTerm);
    if ($pos === false)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
$found = like('Apple', 'app'); //returns true
$notFound = like('Apple', 'lep'); //returns false

if($found){
    // This will execute only when the text is like the desired string
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the input is an array. I got error like: strtolower(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use function, that search string in another string like: `strstr`, `strpos`, `substr_count`.

Answer (score 2):

strpos() is not working for so i have to use this preg_match()

```
$a = 'How are you?';

if (preg_match('/\bare\b/', $a)) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

like in this e.g i am matching with word "are"
hope for someone it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

But you will have to give lowercase string then it will work fine.
Example of strstr function:

```
$myString = "Hello, world!";
echo strstr( $myString, "wor" );                    // Displays 'world!'
echo ( strstr( $myString, "xyz" ) ? "Yes" : "No" ); // Displays 'No'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a MySQL server, send a query like this with MySQLi:

```
$SQL="select case when '$Value' like '$Pattern' then 'True' else 'False' end as Result";
$Result=$MySQLi->query($SQL)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)[0]['Result'];
```

Result will be a string containing True or False. Let PHP do what it's good for and use SQL for likes.

Comment: I think he or she is only looking for a similar syntax or a trick in PHP to do the same thing than the sql 'like' keyword, but I'm not sure he/she is using a database for this.

Comment: Maybe someone doesn't have access to a SQL server, but it begs the question. If you are not using SQL why would you think of trying to mimic a SQL feature in PHP? PHP doesn't have like. It has the regular expression, which is better if you know how to use it, but there's the rub.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this requirement recently and came up with this:

```
/**
 * Removes the diacritical marks from a string.
 *
 * Diacritical marks: {@link https://unicode-table.com/blocks/combining-diacritical-marks/}
 *
 * @param string $string The string from which to strip the diacritical marks.
 * @return string Stripped string.
 */
function stripDiacriticalMarks(string $string): string
{
    return preg_replace('/[\x{0300}-\x{036f}]/u', '', \Normalizer::normalize($string , \Normalizer::FORM_KD));
}

/**
 * Checks if the string $haystack is like $needle, $needle can contain '%' and '_'
 * characters which will behave as if used in a SQL LIKE condition. Character escaping
 * is supported with '\'.
 *
 * @param string $haystack The string to check if it is like $needle.
 * @param string $needle The string used to check if $haystack is like it.
 * @param bool $ai Whether to check likeness in an accent-insensitive manner.
 * @param bool $ci Whether to check likeness in a case-insensitive manner.
 * @return bool True if $haystack is like $needle, otherwise, false.
 */
function like(string $haystack, string $needle, bool $ai = true, bool $ci = true): bool
{
    if ($ai) {
        $haystack = stripDiacriticalMarks($haystack);
        $needle = stripDiacriticalMarks($needle);
    }

    $needle = preg_quote($needle, '/');

    $tokens = [];

    $needleLength = strlen($needle);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $needleLength;) {
        if ($needle[$i] === '\\') {
            $i += 2;
            if ($i < $needleLength) {
                if ($needle[$i] === '\\') {
                    $tokens[] = '\\\\';
                    $i += 2;
                } else {
                    $tokens[] = $needle[$i];
                    ++$i;
                }
            } else {
                $tokens[] = '\\\\';
            }
        } else {
            switch ($needle[$i]) {
                case '_':
                    $tokens[] = '.';
                    break;
                case '%':
                    $tokens[] = '.*';
                    break;
                default:
                    $tokens[] = $needle[$i];
                    break;
            }
            ++$i;
        }
    }

    return preg_match('/^' . implode($tokens) . '$/u' . ($ci ? 'i' : ''), $haystack) === 1;
}

/**
 * Escapes a string in a way that `UString::like` will match it as-is, thus '%' and '_'
 * would match a literal '%' and '_' respectively (and not behave as in a SQL LIKE
 * condition).
 *
 * @param string $str The string to escape.
 * @return string The escaped string.
 */
function escapeLike(string $str): string
{
    return strtr($str, ['\\' => '\\\\', '%' => '\%', '_' => '\_']);
}
```

The code above is unicode aware to be able to catch cases like:

```
like('Hello ', 'Hello _'); // true
like('Hello ', '_e%o__');  // true
like('asdfas \\H\\\\%É\\l\\_\\l\\o asdfasf', '%' . escapeLike('\\h\\\\%e\\l\\_\\l\\o') . '%'); // true
```

You can try all of this on https://3v4l.org/O9LX0

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth mentioning the `str_contains()` function available in **PHP 8** which performs a case-sensitive check indicating whether a string is contained within another string, returning true or false.

Example taken from the documentation:

```
$string = 'The lazy fox jumped over the fence';

if (str_contains($string, 'lazy')) {
    echo "The string 'lazy' was found in the string\n";
}

if (str_contains($string, 'Lazy')) {
    echo 'The string "Lazy" was found in the string';
} else {
    echo '"Lazy" was not found because the case does not match';
}

//The above will output:
//The string 'lazy' was found in the string
//"Lazy" was not found because the case does not match
```

See the full documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php).

Answer (score 0):

like_match() example is the best
this one witch SQL reqest is simple (I used it before), but works slowly then like_match() and exost database server resources when you iterate by array keys and every round hit db server with request usually not necessery. I made it faster ferst cutting / shrink array by pattern elements but regexp on array works always faster.
I like like_match() :)